# Fixed Effect vs. Categorical Variable

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multiple-regression, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to understand the difference between a linear model with a categorical level variable and a linear mixed effects model wherein the slopes are held constant. In a mixed effects model, both the slopes and intercepts may vary across the fixed effect. However, we can also hold the slopes constant across levels of the fixed effect (allowing only the intercepts to vary across each level of the fixed effect).

Isn't ***holding the slope constant and assigning each level of the categorical variable its own intercept*** exactly what is happening in a linear model with a categorical variable?

**For Example**:

Here, I generated a dataset with 3 socio-economic status levels (low, mid, high), age, and daily caloric consumption.

```
library(faux)
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(jtools)

set.seed(69)
df1 = rbind(low = rnorm_multi(n = 500, mu = c(40, 1750), sd = c(5, 100), r = c(-0.5), varnames = c("age", "calories"), empirical = FALSE) %>%
              mutate(ses = rep("low", 500)),
            mid = rnorm_multi(n = 500, mu = c(40, 2150), sd = c(5, 100), r = c(-0.5), varnames = c("age", "calories"), empirical = FALSE) %>%
              mutate(ses = rep("mid", 500)),
            upper = rnorm_multi(n = 500, mu = c(40, 1950), sd = c(5, 100), r = c(0.5), varnames = c("age", "calories"), empirical = FALSE) %>%
              mutate(ses = rep("high", 500)
                     )
            ) %>% tibble()
```

Results

```
head(df1)
               age calories ses
    low.1 42.36550 1757.781 low
    low.2 32.81524 1787.275 low
    low.3 40.28969 1716.505 low
    low.4 39.81675 1654.947 low
    low.5 38.73746 1655.888 low
    low.6 38.62440 1869.002 low
```

Generate and Print Linear Model with Categorical SES

```
linear_m = lm(calories ~ age + ses, df1); summ(simple_lm)
MODEL INFO:
Observations: 1500
Dependent Variable: calories
Type: OLS linear regression 

MODEL FIT:
F(3,1496) = 1420.83, p = 0.00
R² = 0.74
Adj. R² = 0.74 

Standard errors: OLS
---------------------------------------------------
                       Est.    S.E.   t val.      p
----------------- --------- ------- -------- ------
(Intercept)         2088.27   21.49    97.17   0.00
age                   -3.39    0.52    -6.47   0.00
seslow              -205.21    6.18   -33.23   0.00
sesmid               196.16    6.18    31.76   0.00
---------------------------------------------------
```

Generate and Print Linear Mixed Effects Model

```
lmer_m = lmer(calories ~ age + (1|ses), df1); summ(lmer_m)

MODEL INFO:
Observations: 1500
Dependent Variable: calories
Type: Mixed effects linear regression 

MODEL FIT:
AIC = 18018.02, BIC = 18039.28
Pseudo-R² (fixed effects) = 0.01
Pseudo-R² (total) = 0.81 

FIXED EFFECTS:
--------------------------------------------------------------
                       Est.     S.E.   t val.      d.f.      p
----------------- --------- -------- -------- --------- ------
(Intercept)         2095.44   116.99    17.91      2.12   0.00
age                   -3.66     0.50    -7.27   1496.00   0.00
--------------------------------------------------------------

p values calculated using Satterthwaite d.f.

RANDOM EFFECTS:
------------------------------------
  Group      Parameter    Std. Dev. 
---------- ------------- -----------
   ses      (Intercept)    199.55   
 Residual                   97.65   
------------------------------------

Grouping variables:
-------------------------
 Group   # groups   ICC  
------- ---------- ------
  ses       3       0.81 
-------------------------
```

My understanding of mixed effects models (when holding the slope constant) is that *the model is assigning a different intercept to each level of the fixed effect*, is this correct? Further, isn't this exactly the same thing a standard linear model analysis with a categorical variable is doing?

The coefficient for the continuous variable ("random effect") in both analyses here aren't incredibly dissimilar, *but they are different*. So there is obviously something different about these models. Are they two different approaches to the same thing? Why/when would a mixed model be preferred over the standard linear model, and vice versa?